# Difference - "e.preventDefault();" and "return false;"

Tags: javascript

What is difference between `return false;` and `e.preventDefault();` ?

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occuring and `return false` stops propogation.

Comment: Wrong. `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action (not event) from occurring, without stopping further propagation of the event. And on some browsers in some circumstances, `return false` does the same, but there isn't any W3C specification for this.